# /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4)

Tags: ubuntu

I was playing around setting up LDAP but then any subsequent network tool that I use comes up with this error output, how do I fix it?

```
/usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2: no version information available (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4)
```

Comment: I have tried uninstall and reinstalled ldap and still getting this error output.

Answer (score 2):

This means that libcurl-gnutls was compiled against a different version of libldap_r than what you have in /usr/local/lib. See [What does the "no version information available" error from linux dynamic linker mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137773/what-does-the-no-version-information-available-error-from-linux-dynamic-linker) Either delete /usr/local/lib/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 or remove /usr/local/lib from your LD_LIBRARY_PATH.